# Icon, search bar not showing on magento header

Tags: magento, header, magento2

I am working on a magento2 website, suddenly i noticed that cart icon and search bar disappeared and my menu get disorganized and unclickable. I have run the following command but still not working.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

but all not working

can anyone help, here is the website https://micserah.com

Answer (score 0):

Check your store view in System>Configuration>Design>Themes and see what it says there as the templates and layout name (not to be confused with system>design). Make sure it says default/modern or just modern.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your site. So this is designed issues. This is the class "hidden-sm hidden-xs " it's overflow and the same issues in the mini cart and Search icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSWEX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8dCU.png)

Comment: You can specify screenshots of before and after making changes.

Comment: Sure, this is the current site screenshot https://prnt.sc/24wajw0 and after changes screenshot https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19209318?key=164fe493f4841cebba838fed985a6272a

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for the idea, what should I do from here, because the desktop view get disorganized. The menu are unclickeable

Comment: Hi Adex, this is design issues. I think so check the header divs width. Thanks!